# How to query mongodb Date using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to convert this query from php to mongoDB query

```
$query = "select * from table where data_added like '%data%';
```

I have date stored in variable

```
$date = "2013-09-02";
```

and in my mongo Document the date sorted as :

```
$dateAdded = new MongoDate(strtotime('2013-09-02 12:21:55'));
```

I tried

```
$date = new MongoDate(strtotime("$date"));

$mongo->find(array('date_added'=>array('$lt'=>$date)));

and 
$mongo->find(array('date_added'=>$date));
```

but without success .

so I need to query usin **(Y-m-d)** not **(Y-m-d h:i:s)**
so how to use LIKE query for data in mongo

Thanks

Comment: How about `$dateAdded = new MongoDate(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2013-09-02 12:21:55')));`?

Comment: Thanks, but I need $dateAdded = new MongoDate(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2013-09-02')));

Comment: It's already in `Y-m-d` format. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: but it has (h:i:s)  I need without  (h:i:s)

Comment: Look at my first comment again. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this (using `MongoDate`) but that line first converts your date string into a Unix timestamp, and then formats it into `Y-m-d` format using `date()`.

Comment: What data type is in MongoDB? You may need to do a range, `2013-09-22 00:00:00` through `2013-09-22 23:59:59`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a range query. Create a timestamp, for example using strtotime(), to get the unix timestamp at the start of the day, and another one and the end of the day.

Depending on if you want these two ends inclusive or exclusive, you then use

```
// Both points/seconds inclusive
->find(array("date" => array('$gte' => $startOfDay, '$lte' => $endOfDay)));
// Both seconds exclusive
->find(array("date" => array('$gt' => $startOfDay, '$lt' => $endOfDay)));
```

See http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/